# Swagger-UI GET-parameter serialization for nested arrays

Tags: php, swagger

I have this PHP snippet:

```
<?php
$json = '{"number":[{"value":"5121387","operator":"="},{"value":"5121391","operator":"="}]}';
$array = json_decode($json, true);
echo http_build_query($array);
```

and it generates this (for better readability I decoded those %XY Brackets):

```
number[0][value]=5121387&number[0][operator]=%3D&number[1][value]=5121391&number[1][operator]=%3D
```

This is excellent and works for my case.

When I try to generate this form-URL-encoding by Open-API/Swagger-UI it doesnt work this way:

```
[
    'name'   => 'number',
    'in'     => 'query',
    'style'  => 'form',
    'description' => 'some description',
    'explode'=> true,
    'collectionFormat' => 'multi',
    'schema' => [
        [...],
    ],
];
```

instead it generates me this GET-query appended to my URL:

```
number[value]=5121387&number[operator]=%3D&number[value]=5121391&number[operator]=%3D
```

the [Open-API Doc](https://swagger.io/specification/#style-examples) says the same - but it doesnt say how to fix this - the problem is the missing Array-indicators e.g. "[0]":

[image]

I have already checked the swagger-ui-bundle.js from the Swagger-ui to alter the form-encoding myself - but it is minified and I dont get it...

Do you have any Idea how I can teach my .yaml or Swagger-UI to add those numbered brackets for Arrays?